# Where does the .runsettings file go?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage

I want to exclude some files from code coverage in our unit tests. I've learned that the thing to use is a XML file with an extension of .runsettings. Where does the .runsettings file go? Does it go in the unit test project? Or does it go in the project that's being tested by the unit tests project? Or is the .runsettings file all by its lonesome under the solution?

I'm using VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Put it wherever you like.
In VS 2015 you can specify the path and name for your `.runsettings`

Menu: Test->Test Settings-> Select Test Settings File